# set background image in button in datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I am developing a windows application (vb.net, vs 2012, metro ui), but stuck at the point. 
Adding column in datagridview -> runtime 
Adding button in datagridview -> runtime 
using metro UI framework, form layout looks good, but how can I set background image of button in datagridview (method- gv_btn)?

```
Private Sub load_gv_client()
    DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "Name"
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "Company"
    DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
End Sub

Private Sub load_client()
    'code skipped- fetching data from database
    adapter.Fill(dt)
    For Each row In dt.Rows
        populate_client(row(0), row(1))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub populate_client(Name As String, Company As String)
    Dim row As String() = New String() {Name, Company}
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
End Sub

Private Sub gv_btn()
    Dim btn As New DataGridViewButtonColumn
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(btn)
    btn.HeaderText = "Edit"
    btn.Text = "Edit"
    btn.Name = "btn"
    btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True        
End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3977155/2953322

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set image for DataGridViewButtonColumn in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977073/set-image-for-datagridviewbuttoncolumn-in-c-sharp)

Comment: errors: (1) type 'DataGridViewImageButtonCell' is not defined (intellisense shows 'DataGridViewImageButtonDeleteColumn') (2) sub 'lodimages' can not be declared  'overrides' because it does not override a sub in a base class (should I remove 'override' keyword?) (3) '_buttonImageHot' is not declared, it may be inaccessible due to its protection level.